# Trouble forming general solution for linear congruence

Tags: diophantine-equations, congruences, chinese-remainder-theorem

I was given 
$$
6x+14y=4 \space \mod 5
$$

I took this approach:
$$
6x+14y-5z=4, \space \text{ for some } z
$$

Let 
$$
w=\frac{6}{(6,14)}x+\frac{14}{(6,14)}y 
$$

Then,
$$
(6,14)w+5z=4 \quad , \quad 6w+5z=4
$$

where $w=-6$ and $z=8$

Hence, the general solution is

$$
w=-6+5s \quad , \quad z=8-6s
$$

Substitute for $w$ yields

$$
\frac{6}{(6,14)}x+\frac{14}{(6,14)}y =-6+5s \quad,\quad 6x+14y=-6+5s
$$
where $x=\frac{5}{6}s$ and $y=-\frac{3}{7}$ which is a particular solution

Hence, the general solution would be

$$
x=\frac{5}{6}s+14t \quad , \quad y=-\frac{3}{7}-8t
$$

How can I check that this general solution holds true?

Answer (score 1):

${\rm mod}\ 5\!:\ 4\equiv 6x+14y\equiv x-y\iff y\equiv x+1\ $

So the general solution is $\, (x,y) \equiv (x,x\!+\!1) \equiv (0,1) + x(1,1)$

Comment: I don't quite understand how you obtained the general solution :/ @billdubuque

Comment: @iterence The first sentence proves that $(x,y)$ is a solution $\iff y\equiv x\!+\!1,\,$ so the general solution is the "line" $\ y \equiv x+1\ \ $

Comment: @iterence If you can tell me more precisely what you do not understand I can explain further.

Comment: @iterence All the congruences above are modulo $5$. The first line uses $\,6\equiv 1\,$ and $\, 14\equiv -1,\,$ to deduce $\,x-y\equiv 4\,$ so $\,y\equiv x-4\equiv x+1.\,$ Again, if you can be more specific about where you are stuck then I will be happy to explain further.

Comment: I somehow get it now. Not fully but partially. I'll do my best to figure out your methodology. I'll get back to you if I have any doubts about your answer @BillDubuque